Trouble Using TGUI with SFML in C++ Project in Visual Studio 2022
I'm trying to integrate SFML and TGUI libraries into my C++ projects. While SFML works perfectly, I’m having trouble with TGUI.
I followed the installation instructions on the TGUI website carefully—adding the necessary directories and setting the appropriate properties in Visual Studio. However, I get an error when running the following code:
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <TGUI/TGUI.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "TGUI Example");
    tgui::Gui gui(window);

    // Other GUI setup code here

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            gui.handleEvent(event);
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        gui.draw();
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}

I’ve double-checked that the TGUI library is included correctly, but I’m at a loss for what could be going wrong.
Does anyone have any suggestions or solutions?
I tried pretty much everything i could. Double-Checking if i pasted the right directories (i did according to the TGUI installation guide) and also the visual studio project include properties (which also are correct) but this error doesnt seem to go away.
Edit: I checked, and the error message is coming from IntelliSense in Visual Studio. The exact error message is:
Severity: Code  
Description: Namespace "tgui" does not have a member "Gui".  
Project: PhyEng  
File: C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\RandProj\PhyEng\PhyEng\Main.cpp  
Line: 7

The build log says the following at the end:
The build started at 17:37...
1>------ Build started: Project: PhyEng, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Main.cpp
1>C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\RandProj\PhyEng\PhyEng\Main.cpp(9,11): error C2039: 'Gui' is not a member of 'tgui'.
1>    C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\RandProj\PhyEng\include-tgui\TGUI\Widgets\VerticalLayout.hpp(32,30):
1>    See declaration of 'tgui'
1>C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\RandProj\PhyEng\PhyEng\Main.cpp(9,11): error C2065: 'Gui': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\RandProj\PhyEng\PhyEng\Main.cpp(9,15): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'gui'
1>C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\RandProj\PhyEng\PhyEng\Main.cpp(9,15): error C3861: 'gui': identifier not found.
1>C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\RandProj\PhyEng\PhyEng\Main.cpp(15,5): error C2065: 'gui': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\RandProj\PhyEng\PhyEng\Main.cpp(20,5): error C2065: 'gui': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\RandProj\PhyEng\PhyEng\Main.cpp(34,13): error C2065: 'gui': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\RandProj\PhyEng\PhyEng\Main.cpp(38,9): error C2065: 'gui': undeclared identifier
1>The build of the project 'PhyEng.vcxproj' is complete -- ERROR.


The compiler is giving me Are your sure this is the compiler and not IntelliSense? Please post the complete verbatim error message in a code block.

I agree with @3CxEZiVlQ, this message looks nothing like a real compiler error. It may be an Intellisense false positive. All msvc compiler errors should start with C followed by a 4 digit number. If it doesn't start with C its not a compiler error. Here is the list of errors: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/c-cpp-build-errors?view=msvc-170

Does your code actually compile? You can ignore Intellisense errors if you know they are wrong.

Yepp, yall right! I updated the post now. It indeed was from Intellisense

My advice is to check the build log instead of the errors list. The build log should be in the Output tab of your IDE.

@drescherjm nope, i cannot compile it.

@drescherjm i added the build log "error" at the end of the post

That's not the output from the compiler, but some IDE parse of it simplifying it.  Can you find the actual output from the compiler.  Visual Studio C++ compiler messages contain a Cxxxx code and a detailed description.

Namespace tgui indeed does not have a member Gui. You may need tgui::GuiSFML, which also requires some additional includes to pull sfml backend.

From personal experience; tgui works great with sfml. If it doesn't for you, please pose your exact compilation and linking steps.

1>The build of the project can you post the lines of error message above this?

@RichardCritten the only thing i found is "E0135" as code

@drescherjm i added the whole build log n ow

Thanks for the build log! This improves the question for the purpose of the site. I believe @user7860670 may be correct: https://tgui.eu/documentation/0.9/classtgui_1_1GuiSFML.html and also see this example code: https://tgui.eu/tutorials/latest-stable/backend-sfml-graphics/

Looks like (from the SFML example code on the TGUI page) you need to add: #include <TGUI/Backend/SFML-Graphics.hpp> to the includes.

@drescherjm no way, thank you so much. Its working now after adding that include!!

From the TGUI documentation: https://tgui.eu/documentation/0.9/classtgui_1_1GuiSFML.html and the example SFML program https://tgui.eu/tutorials/latest-stable/backend-sfml-graphics/ you appear to be missing an include.
Please add:
#include <TGUI/Backend/SFML-Graphics.hpp>

to your includes.
A minimal TGUI program that uses SFML as the GUI backend would be the following:
#include <TGUI/TGUI.hpp>
#include <TGUI/Backend/SFML-Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window{{800, 600}, "TGUI example - SFML_GRAPHICS backend"};
    tgui::Gui gui{window};
    gui.mainLoop(); // See below for how to use your own main loop
}

